# Remove Border from Control Panel buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to remove border from the buttons on the Gps tracking Control Panel.
The button on the click shows the blue border, so I do not want that border on the buttons, here is the picture how its looks like : 
https://ibb.co/RDHGX3f

Please, can you inspect it and tell me what do I need to do, to remove that border from the buttons!

and I tried this code to insert but nothing:

```
.x-toolbar .x-btn {
    border: none!important;
    border-radius: 15px!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This border is only shown when the item is "focused". use CSS pseudo-selector :focus and remove the outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an outline.

```
outline:none;
```

Comment: thank you, that is correct my friend.